# Read camera device name and store it as a variable in c#

Tags: c#, windows-10, device-manager

I would like to Read the name of USB camera (i.e., HD USB camera) attached to Windows 10 and store the name as a variable in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to filter the items in the `Win32_PnPEntity` class to only show items referring to the **IMAGE** or **MEDIA** category, which usually list items referring to the webcam connected to usb.

In the SQL command you can change the category.

```
    using System.Management;  

    private static void GetUSBDevices()
    {
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')");

        foreach (var device in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Device: {device["PNPClass"]} / {device["Caption"]}");
        }
    }
```

You will need to add the System.Management dependency to the project.

Comment: I changed the "Win32_PnPSignedDriver" library to "Win32_PnPEntity" that best suits what you asked.